# ASP.net - "INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR "=""

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to log in using values from two different tables using ASP.NET, but I get this error:

> INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR "="

Code:

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Company_Master.Company_Code ='" + TextBox1.Text + "',Employee_Master.Emp_ID ='" + TextBox2.Text + "',Employee_Master.Emp_Pass ='" + Password1.Text + "' from Company_Master, Employee_Master where Company_Master.Company_Code = Employee_Master.Company_Code;");

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            sda.Fill(dt);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                

            sda.Fill(ds, "Company_Master,Employee_Master");

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Label1.Text = "sign up done";
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "wrong login";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Read about SQL injection: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp. It won't solve this problem, but it will prevent many other far more serious problems in future.

Comment: Filters should be in a where clause, not in the select. Please use parameters to prevent all sorts of problems. And use an explicit "join" clause

Comment: Also, why are you executing your query **three times**?? `sda.Fill(dt);`, then `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` (which is utterly pointless for a `SELECT` query that **returns data**), and then a third time with `sda.Fill(ds, "Company_Master,Employee_Master");` ..... once a `.Fill()` would be **quite** enough!

Answer (score 2):

Did someone tell you that you are allowing attackers to penetrate into your `db` and get any information or delete whatever they want? No?

I must say Praveen, you should always use parameterized queries or try using `Stored Procedures` to read/write/delete anything from your db.

Moreover, the query you have there does not make any sense so, I assume you want to select select something where `company_code` is equal to something, and `employee id` is equal to something and `password` is equal to something.

Here it is how it should be done, keeping the `SqlInjections` in mind.

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Company_Master cm join Employee_Master em on cm.Company_Code = em.Company_Code where cm.Company_Code = @companyCode and em.Emp_ID = @employeeId and em.Emp_Pass = @password", conn))
            {

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyCode", TextBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeId", TextBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Password1.Text);

                conn.Open();

                var sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(sdr);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Label1.Text = "sign up done";
                }
                else
                {
                    Label1.Text = "wrong login";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
}
```

Notice, I have modified your query to support sql `join` and I have modified the query to be a parameterized query in a `using` block. Plus, the dataset was modified to DataTable as I noticed you were not getting multiple tables and were referencing to the zeroth index of the dataset `Tables`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String mycon = "Data Source =EL-0\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=dbsBookManagementSystemAshnu;user id=sa;password=loncok#08";
            String myquery = "select bk_bookid,bk_bookname,bk_author,bk_bookdescription,bk_price,bk_specialprice from bmsa_books where bk_bookid = " + Request.QueryString["bk_bookid"];
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mycon);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
            {
                CommandText = myquery,
                Connection = con
            };
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter
            {
                SelectCommand = cmd
            };
            DataSet ds=new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds,"bmsa_books");
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                lblBookID.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["bk_bookid"].ToString();
                lblBookName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["bk_bookname"].ToString();
                lblAuthor.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["bk_author"].ToString();
                lblDescription.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["bk_bookdescription"].ToString();
                lblPrice.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["bk_price"].ToString();
                lblSpecialPrice.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["bk_specialprice"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Formatting required